# Как открывать проекты Qt в Visual Studio

Tags: qt, visual-studio

Ввёл версию Qt в Visual Studio и указал путь к файлу `mingw_64`. Выходит следующая ошибка (см. ниже). С чем может быть связано? Посмотрел гайд в ютубе, человек делает всё также не устанавливая какие-то компиляторы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем Вам mingw в Visual Studio? В колонке Compiler даже написано - msvc.

Comment: в таком случае нужно что то в Visual Studio что то настроить? если да, то какие моменты исправить?

Comment: Я оставил инструкцию по созданию проекта sln из pro файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Открыть `Command Prompt` для Visual Studio требуемой версии и архитектуры.
2. В консоли активируете среду `Qt` - `pathToQt/X.X.X/msvc20XX_xx/bin/qtenv2.bat`.
3. Настраиваете окружение Visual Studio `C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsXX.bat`.
4. Перейти в директорию с .pro файлом.
5. Запустить `qmake.exe -tp vc` для .pro файла.
6. Открываете полученный файл .sln или .vcxproj в Visual Studio.

В случае возникновения на этапе 5 ошибки
`Project ERROR: msvc-version.conf loaded but QMAKE_MSC_VER isn't set`
[прописываете руками QMAKE_MSC_VER, соответствующее версии Visual Studio в файл msvc-version.conf в самом начале](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665166/qmake-msc-ver-isnt-set)